# ETL data structure

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph

Let's suppose I have an ETL flow as follows:

```
source1 ---> do_filter ---> join -----> output
                             ^
                             |
source2 ---------------------
```

What would be the proper data structure to represent this? My thought was having a `from: to[]` structure.

Comment: It depends what graph operations you want to use most often. `from: to[]` a.k.a. an [adjacency list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) is a good general-purpose graph data structure, but it's not always the best option. What do you want to do with the graph?

Comment: @kaya3 -- thanks for the feedback. Basically to store this as a single json object or array, so that we can recreate ETL 'versions' as the user has saved them.

Comment: I see; so it's just for serialization/deserialization? In that case an adjacency list seems fine, though if storage size/transmission speed is an issue and the graphs are big, you could avoid writing node names multiple times by assigning each node an integer id, using those in the adjacency list, and having a separate array for the node names as strings.

Comment: @kaya3 -- I see, thanks for the feedback. Would you be able to show an answer how the above ETL pipeline would look using an adjacency list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems from the comments that you want to use a JSON format to store and load these graphs, so a simple data structure that doesn't use too much space should be fine. An [adjacency list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) (what you described as `from: to[]`) is a good general purpose graph data structure, and probably suitable for your use-case.

An adjacency list can be implemented in various ways. The simplest way is as a dictionary mapping each node to its list of neighbours:

```
{
    "source1":   ["do_filter"],
    "do_filter": ["join"],
    "join":      ["output"],
    "output":    [],
    "source2":   ["join"]
}
```

If all you need to store is the names of the nodes and the graph's topology, this is probably fine. However, for large graphs with many edges, the JSON will take up more space than necessary because each node's name is written as a string for every edge to that node. If a more compact representation is required, you could use a numeric ID to refer to the nodes:

```
{
    "nodes": ["source1", "do_filter", "join", "output", "source2"],
    "edges": [[1], [2], [3], [], [2]]
}
```

Here `source1` is node 0, `do_filter` is node 1, and so on, based on their indices in `nodes`; so the edge from `source1` to `do_filter` is represented by `edges[0]` containing the number `1`. Similarly, `edges[3]` is empty, indicating `nodes[3]`, i.e. `output`, has no edges to other nodes.

Another option if you need to store more information about each node (e.g. x,y coordinates for drawing it, colour, etc.) is to make each node an object. This is still an adjacency list, because it represents the topology of the graph by associating each node with a list of its neighbours:

```
[
    { "name": "source1",   "colour": "green",  "edges": [1] },
    { "name": "do_filter", "colour": "red",    "edges": [2] },
    { "name": "join",      "colour": "orange", "edges": [3] },
    { "name": "output",    "colour": "blue",   "edges": [] },
    { "name": "source2",   "colour": "black",  "edges": [2] }
]
```

Comment: thanks for this, could you please explain how `"edges": [[1], [2], [3], [], [2]]` is arrived at? What does `[1]` mean?

Comment: thanks for the update. So an example edge would be read as: `The node at index 0, "source1", is connected to the node(s) at index 1, "do_filter"`, correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. More formally, `j` is a member of `edges[i]` if and only if `nodes[i]` has an edge to `nodes[j]`.